# Upgrading web parts from SP 2013 to SP 2016

Tags: web-part, 2016

We have various web parts targeting SP 2013. I now have a SP 2016 Beta server with VS 2015 installed. I don't see any template in VS to create 2016 web part or a way to upgrade web part project to target SP 2016.

One of the web parts worked with 2016 directly (wsp created on 2013) but another one is not working so I am keen to understand the process of supporting and migrating 2013 web parts to 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install [Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49972). then you will get SharePoint 2016 Template.

[image]

Find more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/11/23/latest-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2015/)

After installing this tool, just open your 2013 solution, it will be automatically converted to 2016. Then find the problems.